# `require('path')` but not visible in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, path

I am looking at the following tutorial https://github.com/jakblak/thinkster_mean_app/blob/master/app.js and can see that `require('path')` is present in the app.js. However, `package.json` does not seem to explicitly install it? So where is `path` being taken from? Is it present by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`path` is a NodeJS built-in module, so there is no need to add it over npm. Its already available when you install NodeJS like `Console` module or `os` module.

Here is the available [path documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path) which can give you more details about `path` itself.

And [here](https://nodejs.org/api/documentation.html) is the list of all built-in modules and high-level concepts.